# Cookie “TempData” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, samesite, tempdata

I am seeing the following error in FireFox:

> Cookie “TempData” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite”
> attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure”
> attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read
> https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

My website is developed in ASP.NET MVC 5, how can I set the SameSite attribute for `TempData`?

Comment: Error reads Cookie named TempData not the session TempData I guess. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Note that you can instead set the "secure" attribute, you have two options.

Comment: @JBallin: thanks but how do I do this?